# Snake game grid system

Tags: c++, grid, codeblocks

I am currently stuck trying to create a grid for my controllable snake to move around. Currently. I am using a resolution of 1024x768 and would like the snake to move between a 16x16 grid (64x48 resolution)

So far the snake just moves pixel by pixel at a set speed.

I'll paste the .cpp and .hpp files below which i think are relevant to where i need to implement the code. If anyone could provide any suggestions/code that would be great!

**snake.cpp**

```
#include "snake.hpp"

#include <cstdlib>

void Snake::move()
{
    switch(direction_){
    case Direction::North:
        position_.y += 1;
        break;
    case Direction::East:
        position_.x += 1;
        break;
    case Direction::South:
        position_.y -= 1;
        break;
    case Direction::West:
        position_.x -= 1;
    }

    if (position_.x < 0) position_.x = 63; else if (position_.x > 63) position_.x = 0;
    if (position_.y < 0) position_.y = 47; else if (position_.y > 47) position_.y = 0;
}

void Snake::render(prg::Canvas& canvas) const
{
    canvas.drawCircle(getPosition().x * 16, getPosition().y * 16,16,prg::Colour::WHITE);
}

void Snake::changeDirection(Direction new_direction)
{
    direction_ = new_direction;
}
```

**snake.hpp**

```
#if !defined SNAKE_HPP
#define SNAKE_HPP

#include <prg_interactive.hpp>


enum class Direction {
    North = 1, East, South, West
};

struct Position final {
    int x{0}, y{0};
    Position(int ix, int iy) : x{ix}, y{iy} {}
};

class Snake {
public:
    virtual ~Snake() {}
    virtual void move();
    void render(prg::Canvas& canvas) const;
    void changeDirection(Direction new_direction);
    const Position& getPosition() const {return position_;}
    void setPosition(const Position& position){ position_ = position;}

 private:
    Direction direction_ {Direction::North};
    Position position_ {0,0};
};


    class PlayerSnake : public Snake,
                        public prg::IKeyEvent {
    public:
        PlayerSnake();
        virtual ~PlayerSnake();
        bool onKey(const prg::IKeyEvent::KeyEvent& key_event) override;
};


#endif // SNAKE_HPP
```

**play_state.cpp**

```
#include "play_state.hpp"
#include "ai_snake.hpp"
#include "player_snake.hpp"
#include <iostream>

const size_t MaxShapes {5};
const unsigned int MaxScale {5};

bool PlayState::onCreate()
{
    snakes_.push_back(new AISnake);
    snakes_.back()->setPosition(Position(100,100));
    snakes_.push_back(new PlayerSnake);
    snakes_.back()->setPosition(Position(50,50));

    double x, y;
    for(unsigned shape = 0;shape < MaxShapes;shape++)
    {
        x = (double)(rand() % prg::application.getScreenWidth());
        y = (double)(rand() % prg::application.getScreenHeight());

        shapes_.push_back(Square({x, y}));

    }
    return true;
}

bool PlayState::onDestroy()
{
    return true;
}

void PlayState::onEntry()
{
    prg::application.addKeyListener(*this);
    game_timer_.start();
}

void PlayState::onExit()
{
    prg::application.removeKeyListener(*this);
    game_timer_.stop();
}

void PlayState::onUpdate()
{

}

void PlayState::onRender(prg::Canvas& canvas)
{
    const std::string text = "";

    canvas.blitFast(
        background_,
        canvas.getWidth() / 2 - background_.getWidth() / 2,
        canvas.getHeight() / 2 - background_.getHeight() / 2
    );

    prg::uint text_dims[2];
    prg::Font::MASSIVE.computePrintDimensions(text_dims, text);
    prg::Font::MASSIVE.print(
      canvas,
      prg::application.getScreenWidth() / 2 - text_dims[0] / 2,
      prg::application.getScreenHeight() / 2 - text_dims[1] / 2,
      prg::Colour::RED,
      text);

    for(const auto snake : snakes_) {
    snake->render(canvas);
    }

    for(Shape shapes : shapes_) {
    shapes.render(canvas);
    }
}

bool PlayState::onKey(const prg::IKeyEvent::KeyEvent& key_event)
{
    if(key_event.key_state == KeyEvent::KB_DOWN) {
        switch(key_event.key) {
        case KeyEvent::KB_ESC_KEY:
            prg::application.exit();
            break;

        }
    }
    return true;
}

void PlayState::onTimer(prg::Timer& timer)
{
    for(auto snake : snakes_) {
        snake->move();
    }
}
```

**play_state.hpp**

```
#if !defined PLAY_STATE_HPP
#define PLAY_STATE_HPP

#include <prg_interactive.hpp>
#include "snake.hpp"
#include "square.hpp"
#include <list>


//Example of forward declaration of Snake class
class Snake;

class PlayState final : public prg::IAppState,
                        public prg::IKeyEvent,
                        public prg::ITimerEvent {
public:
    PlayState() = default;
    bool onCreate() override;
    bool onDestroy() override;
    void onEntry() override;
    void onExit() override;
    void onUpdate() override;
    void onRender(prg::Canvas& canvas) override;

    bool onKey(const prg::IKeyEvent::KeyEvent& key_event) override;
    void onTimer(prg::Timer& timer) override;

private:
    //Snake* snakes_[2] {nullptr,nullptr};
    std::list<Snake*> snakes_;
    prg::Timer game_timer_ {0, 1000 / 30, *this};
    const prg::Image background_ {prg::ImageFile("resources/images/border.bmp").load()};

        std::vector<Shape> shapes_;
};

#endif // PLAY_STATE_HPP
```

**player_snake.cpp**

```
#include "player_snake.hpp"


//PlayerSnake Implementation
//
PlayerSnake::PlayerSnake()
{
    prg::application.addKeyListener(*this);
}

PlayerSnake::~PlayerSnake()
{
    prg::application.removeKeyListener(*this);
}

bool PlayerSnake::onKey(const prg::IKeyEvent::KeyEvent& key_event)
{
    if(key_event.key_state == KeyEvent::KB_DOWN) {
        switch(key_event.key) {

        case KeyEvent::KB_LEFT_KEY:
            changeDirection(Direction::West);
            break;
        case KeyEvent::KB_RIGHT_KEY:
            changeDirection(Direction::East);
            break;
        case KeyEvent::KB_UP_KEY:
            changeDirection(Direction::North);
            break;
        case KeyEvent::KB_DOWN_KEY:
            changeDirection(Direction::South);
            break;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

**player_snake.hpp**

```
#if !defined PLAYER_SNAKE_HPP
#define PLAYER_SNAKE_HPP

#include "snake.hpp"
#include <prg_interactive.hpp>

#endif //PLAYER_SNAKE_HPP
```

Comment: Your game would be easier to expand if you used named identifiers (#define or const int) instead of `63` or `47`.  For example: `const unsigned int MAXIMUM_WIDTH = 64;`.

Comment: Try using the modulo operator for your wrap-around:  `position.x = (position.x + 1) % MAXIMUM_WIDTH; ` and `position.x = (position + MAXIMUM_WIDTH - 1) % MAXIMUM_WIDTH;`

Comment: I'd use 64x48 field with offsets raising by 1 under the hood. Then I'd convert the coordinates at the render phase by multiplying by 16.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, i've been trying to implement what you're saying but i am pretty new to and limited with C++ code.

what can i add to the code above to achieve this?

Comment: Why does `Snake` class have a destructor but no constructors or assignment operators?  Read up on [The Rule of Three](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three).  Also read up on Scott Myer's books "Effective C++" and "More Effective C++".  The books give details about when to use constructors, destructors and assignment operators.

Comment: Also, you should place one class per header file.  This allows you to only include one class when needed, without having the extra baggage.  Same rule to source files.

Comment: This expression, "1000 / 30" is bothering me.  They are integers and integer division truncates (no remainders).  This is the same as "100/3).  Did you really want to truncate the remainder?  Otherwise use "1000.0 / 30.0", note the decimal points to indicate floating point arithmetic.

Comment: i've had a look at implementing identifiers as you mentioned, where specifically in the code i already have should they be going? i don't suppose you could edit them into my code?

also, whereabouts did you see the use of 1000 / 30?

Answer (score 1):

### You snake is initially set out of bounds:

```
snakes_.push_back(new AISnake);
snakes_.back()->setPosition(Position(100,100));
snakes_.push_back(new PlayerSnake);
snakes_.back()->setPosition(Position(50,50));
```

Because in the `move` function, you limit the snake to `(64, 48)` as the maximum location.  The x position 100 is past the limit.  The `y` positions are past the limit.

You may want to set them at different locations based on the MAXIMUM_WIDTH and MAXIMUM_HEIGHT constants (see my comments):

```
Snake AISnake;
AISnake.setPosition(MAXIMUM_WIDTH / 4, MAXIMUM_HEIGHT / 4);
snakes_.push_back(AISnake);
Snake PlayerSnake;
PlayerSnake.setPosition(MAXIMUM_WIDTH * 3 / 4,
                        MAXIMUM_HEIGHT * 3 / 4);
snakes_.push_back(PlayerSnake);
```

Also note that in the above code fragment, there is no dynamic memory allocation.  The variables (snakes) are defined locally and **copied** into the `snakes_` container.  This means that there is no need to worry about memory leaks or memory management (like when to delete the memory occupied by the snake).

### More Out Of Bounds

Some places, you use the screen dimensions for the boundaries, others, you use a hard coded value:

```
x = (double)(rand() % prg::application.getScreenWidth());
y = (double)(rand() % prg::application.getScreenHeight());
```

You need to decide whether the game board occupies the entire screen dimensions or is a fixed size.  If you keep the above statements, you should test the positions to verify they are within the game borders.

If this is a GUI application, you need to decide on a fixed size game board or a board set to the size of the window or expanding to the entire screen.  For a fixed size board, you should consider a "viewport" design.  This means that the window is a view or port showing a small portion of the board (the board is bigger than the window).

### Separation of Screen Vs. Board

You should separate the concepts between a logical board and the physical screen.  This concept lets you adapt the board to the screen without affecting any other modules.

For example, the `Board` draws onto the screen.  A `Board` cell may have different pixel dimensions depending on the screen resolution.  However, a part of the snake will always occupy at least one `Board` cell.  So the snake movement doesn't depend on the screen resolution, only the `Board` dimensions.

By placing the objects, `Board` and `Screen`, in separate files, you can change the screen dimensions without having to recompile any of the snake or main files.

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed answer, i appreciate the help! i basically just want the resolution to be 1024x768 and for those pixels to be made up of a grid with the snake moving from one block to another. I've tried a few things you've mentioned and am going wrong somewhere. I've no idea how to divide the game board into a grid in the way i described